# Javascript: How to call multiple promise function parallel using observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have multiple promise functions as:

```
function test1(){
     const numberPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
          resolve(1);
     });
     return numberPromise;
}

function test2(){
     const numberPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
          resolve(2);
     });
     return numberPromise;
}

function test3(){
      const numberPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
          resolve(3);
      });
      return numberPromise;
}
```

I want to call it parallel just like `Promise.all([test1(),test2(),test3()])` but I don't want to use promise, I want to use **Observable**.

To get this done I am doing this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
var data=Observable.of(test1(),test2(),test3());
    data.subscribe((data)=>{
            console.log("data :",data);
})
```

But I am getting the result like : 
[image]

But I want to get this like :

```
data :1
data :2
data :3



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wamC.png
```

Comment: Promises are executed async doesn't that make them parallel ?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [forkjoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

```
const example = forkJoin(
  //emit 'Hello' immediately
  of('Hello'),
  //emit 'World' after 1 second
  of('World').pipe(delay(1000)),
  //emit 0 after 1 second
  interval(1000).pipe(take(1)),
  //emit 0...1 in 1 second interval
  interval(1000).pipe(take(2)),
  //promise that resolves to 'Promise Resolved' after 5 seconds
  myPromise('RESULT')
);
//output: ["Hello", "World", 0, 1, "Promise Resolved: RESULT"]
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

[Example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-mzbcrw?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100).